# SSRS 2012 Custom Code/Expression for Divide by Zero and calculations

Tags: reporting-services

I know similar questions have been asked. However, I have not found anything that exactly helps me out in my situation.

I need to avoid divide by zero but before I do a divide with another column value, I am performing a math calculation:

```
=Sum((Fields!col1.Value) - Sum(Fields!col2.Value) / Sum(Fields!col2.Value))
```

I basically want to do a subtraction first, then a divide but I am unable to get the expression or the custom code to work for me. And before I spend too many hours on this one, I figured I would reach out for help.

This is the code I have come up with so far and it works, but I want the column to show nothing instead of 0:

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!LWCasesBudget.Value) = 0, 0, 
Sum(Fields!LWShipQuantity.Value) - Sum(Fields!LWCasesBudget.Value))/ 
IIf(Sum(Fields!LWCasesBudget.Value) = 0, 1, Sum(Fields!LWCasesBudget.Value))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS divide by zero error expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609939/ssrs-divide-by-zero-error-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are happy with your calculation. If the 0 is the only issue then try and replace the 0 with the word "nothing".

Example:

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!LWCasesBudget.Value) = 0, nothing, 
Sum(Fields!LWShipQuantity.Value) - Sum(Fields!LWCasesBudget.Value))/ 
IIf(Sum(Fields!LWCasesBudget.Value) = 0, 1, Sum(Fields!LWCasesBudget.Value))
```

Hope that helps.